# How to stop spreading of eval(gzinflate(base64_decode())); in server?

Tags: php

In my server many files got the following line added with in the files...

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('some code')));
```

I have cleared it once and still it comes again. Can any one help me in stopping this and not to spread anymore?

Comment: There's nothing we can do without seeing the 'some code' part.

Comment: Your pipe is leaking - so removing puddles won't change anything until you fix the actual hole. I hope that plumbing analogy is closer to you than programming.

Comment: @zerkms He may need to go out to the street and shut off the main line.

Comment: @zerkms No, more literally, to pull the plug on the operation until the problem can be fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Your server is compromised! Removing that snippet of php in your files doesn't help one bit if you are not finding how it got there in the first place, and plugging *that* security hole. Ideally, you even want to take your server offline until you've figured out your next steps. Goes without saying that credentials need to be changed, users need to be informed to change their pwd, and a general audit of your server is required (check data consistency, etc.)

just fyi: in some instances what you wrote above as "some code" can be a full blown server administration interface with a db manager!

As to where to look for the source of the vulnerability, you can look at the usual suspects:

- is any of your code writing to files? if so which one? are you computing file names from user input? is that sanitized?
- Do you have file upload functionality? If yes, are the uploaded files directly servable by the web server? Are they in a directory where they can be executed as php file? Note: if you're using a CMS, it's likely you *do* have file upload!
- who has ssh/ftp access to your server? Are you able to check access log?
- If you are using a CMS, who has access to the admin panel, audit logs, change credentials for everybody

Sucks to be in your position right now, but best of luck troubleshooting.

Comment: Your answer is nice and valid, though the only solution for the OP is to hire someone ))